# Merge bookmark into head

Tags: mercurial

I am going from git to mercurial. Trying to find the equivalent of git-branches, I run into mercurial-bookmarks.

Given that I have no bookmarks. The workflow I follow is:

```
hg bookmark test_bookmark
hg update test_bookmark
```

How can I merge that back to the head, since there is no main bookmark?

Comment: Can you go into a little bit more detail about what sort of workflow you have in mind?  After you create the bookmark, do you make any commits?  Are you "sharing" the bookmark in a distributed fashion with other developers?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to commit my changes in the bookmark and then merge the bookmark into HEAD. Similar to git's branches. You branch out, commit in your branch and merge your branch in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of heads with `hg heads`.  This will usually include the bookmarked head along with any other heads you may have created.  If, after pulling, there is exactly one head, there is nothing to merge (your history is linear).  You may want to delete the bookmark in this case with `hg book -d name_of_bookmark`.

On projects which make extensive use of bookmarks, it is common to bookmark the "canonical" head `@`.  This bookmark is checked out automatically when cloning (unless the user passes the `-u` or `-U` flags), and is roughly analogous to git's master branch, except that it doesn't exist by default.  It helps keep track of which head to merge with, but unlike git, you don't need to give every head a name if you don't want to.

If you want to do a fast-forward merge (i.e. you want to move a bookmark forward to a descendant changeset), update to the descendant and do `hg book name_of_bookmark`.  It's somewhat common to fast-forward `@` in this fashion, if your repository is using it.